# Execute C# Procedure from Outlook Email

Tags: c#, outlook

I have an Outlook Html Email with button on it:

```
<div style="width: 100px; float: left">
      <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://..." style="height:40px;display:inline-block;v-text-anchor:middle;width:100px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#1e3650" fillcolor="#369d07">
        <w:anchorlock/>
        <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;">Да</center>
      </v:roundrect>
</div>
```

After I clicked on the button, browser opens and executes function (C# void function) by link.
Is it possible to execute function from outlook button without opening browser?
I need button to make a call and do nothing else.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to write it in VBScript, yes.

Comment: You can execute from a http request instead of a web so a window doesn't open.

Answer (score 1):

For that, you need something like Service which having an endpoint on button click you can do HTTP call to service and particular service will call stored procedure.